# Recommendation for mounting transfer switch to vinyl sided exterior wall

Tags: electrical, mounting, vinyl-siding, transfer-switch

I need to mount a Generac automatic transfer switch to my house beneath the meter base. The construction of the wall I need to mount to is (from outside inwards):

1. 30 yr old vinyl siding (for which I cannot buy new siding to match)
2. R7 foam-board, 3/4(?) thick (a regrettable decision in retrospect--wish I had used 5/8 plywood for all walls)
3. 2x4s 16" o.c.
4. 1/2" drywall

I think I have basically two options:

1. cut and remove all material that'd be behind the automatic transfer switch, mount 1 or 2 layers of 3/4" plywood to studs on either side

or

2. mount the plywood directly over the vinyl siding--making sure it is large enough to fasten to two (or more) studs. I would use long lag bolts and washers to ensure that they didn't pull thru the plywood. I estimate lags will be 3/8x3". The thing I dislike about this option is maintaining/painting the plywood and preventing the need to ever have to replace it.

Option 2  would be easiest and I am not convinced that Option 1  is sufficiently more structurally sound than option 2.
Is it worth the risk of damaging the irreplaceable siding?

Are there better options I have not considered?

and are there any electrical related concerns (with either approach)?

The wall is east-facing and sees little direct precipitation although lots of direct sun.

Comment: option 3 is to cut through the drywall and install plywood or blocking between the studs, not that I'd recommend this approach unless you're really worried about how it looks from outside.  obviously a non-starter if the drywall is inaccessible or covered with irreplaceable mural or wallpaper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first option that comes to mind is [U-strut](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Superstrut-1-5-8-in-x-13-16-in-Gold-Galvanized-Half-Slot-Channel-Strut/3128119). (*Channel strut or C-channel*)

[image]
Photo from fireequip.com.au

The first two struts would be mounted vertically  on studs with at least  three points. Use   [double ended lag screws](https://www.stainlessfastener.com.au/products/stainless-hardware/double-end-lag-screw-grade-316/), (*wood threads on one side and machine threads on the other*)

[image]

Pilot drill through the siding/foam board and into a stud. Drive the appropriate length lag in so that a nut on it will be proud of the siding. Then on each lag goes a nut, big flat washer, U-strut, washer nut. Now you have two solid vertical rails to work with.

You can mount horizontal U-strut to these or a board, You have many options.

A YouTube [search](http://U-strut) will give many sources of info on U-strut.

Comment: I love this site--for this reason! Great answer--and one I would never have thought of. Thank you!!

Comment: This worked out great. I had difficulty finding large double-ended lag screws; otherwise, it was a perfect solution. Thanks Alaska man!